# Can I create a calendar view with schema.xml and map custom columns for the dates?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to create a view for my list, and set the view to be Type Calendar. I also want to map custom fields such as MyStartDate to EventDate and MyEndDate to EndDate

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calendar view by clicking **Create View** button on the ribbon.

[image]

Select **Calendar View**.

[image]

Set you custom date columns as the **Begin** and **End** date.
[image]

After creating the calendar view for the list, you can use [SharePoint Manager for Online](https://spcb.codeplex.com/) to check the **HtmlSchemaXml** for this view.